# Regarding the normal closure of a finite extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I was wondering how to find the normal closure of Q(∜2) in K, where K is the algebraic closure of the set of rationals.

I think the normal closure should be Q(∜2,i),based on the fact that it is the splitting field of the polynomial  f(x)=x^4+2 over Q, but the task ahead is if I am right, how to show it is the smallest normal extension?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your answer is correct that is the normal closure. To show this, we have to assume that there is another field extension $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ that is the normal closure. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is $x^4-2$ (why?), and that has roots, $\pm \sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$. So all this $4$ elements are in $E$, and thus, the quotient $(i\sqrt[4]{2})/(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is also in $E$ cause we are in a field, so $i$ is in $E$, so $E$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ and that means that this is the smallest one.

Comment: Great; thank you. I got it; my remaining concern is that what was the role of K, which is the algebraic closure of the set of rationals? I could not spot its role within the proof.

Comment: you need it because you need to extend your field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ to something bigger (namely you need to add $i$), so this $i$ comes from $K$.

Comment: I see :-), awesome!

Comment: And the degree of this normal closure will be 8. Isnt it?